# GeoPandas intersects doesn't find any intersection

Tags: python, intersection, geopandas

I want to check if points layer that I have intersect with polygons layer that I have, as Boolean column in the points dataframe.
I have two GeoPandas dataframes, the first one is many points and looks like this:

```
>>>ID  geometry
0  12  POINT (5.0279 7.4547)
1  45  POINT (6.6539 12.139)
...
```

and the second dataframe is one layer of many different polygons  that looks something like this:

```
>>>name     code   geometry
0  Desert   12     POLYGON ((5.52013 13.8902, 5.5265 13.892,...)
1  Water    24     POLYGON ((5.53756 13.88472, 5.5291 13.8791,...)
...
```

I'm trying to check if there is any intersection between the points layer and the regions layer. For that I have determined the crs and then used intersects :

```
regions=regions.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})
points=points.set_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})
inter=points.geometry.intersects(regions.geometry)
```

A
The script runs with the following warnings:

> FutureWarning: '+init=:`' syntax is deprecated.
> ':' is the preferred initialization method. When
> making the change, be mindful of axis order changes:
> https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6
> return _prepare_from_string(" ".join(pjargs))
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/base.py:39:
> UserWarning: The indices of the two GeoSeries are different.
>
> warn("The indices of the two GeoSeries are different.")`

Then when I check the results the only value is False, like all th epoints do not intersect:

```
inter.unique().tolist()
>>>[False]
```

*I saw on QGIS that the there are points that intersect and there are points that do not so there is no way this result is true

*I have checked the dtypes - each one of my geodataframes has one column that is geometry and called geometry.

My end goal: to add new column in the points geodataframe that will tell if it intersects the regions or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Intersects is row-wise operation which aligns both GeoSeries and check is a geometry A in row 0 intersects geometry B in row 0. See the documentation on that: https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.intersects.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.intersects

For check if there is any intersection, use spatial index.

```py
import numpy as np

inp, res = regions.sindex.query_bulk(points.geometry, predicate='intersects')
points['intersects'] = np.isin(np.arange(0, len(points)), inp)
```

Regarding the CRS warning, just remove `init` part and pass it as a string.

```py
regions=regions.to_crs('epsg:4326')
points=points.set_crs('epsg:4326')
```

`query_bulk` requires geopandas 0.8. You can check the docs - https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sindex.SpatialIndex.query_bulk.html#geopandas.sindex.SpatialIndex.query_bulk

Comment: thank you for your answer, the problem is that even though the geometry columns are type geometry, when I try this I get error "TypeError: Got `geometry` of type `<class 'str'>`, `geometry` must be a shapely geometry."

Comment: That means that your geometry column contains strings instead of shapely.geometry. You will have to convert those incorrect ones. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433138/converting-a-column-of-polygons-from-string-to-geopandas-geometry/56433910#56433910

Comment: @martinflies that doesn't work ,TypeError: Only str is accepted.  and the dtype is geometry so I'm not sure how can it have string, if you could elaborate regard this that could be great, probably something that Id on't understand

Comment: I ffound the problem- I had also to put ".geometry" after the points dataframe in the beackets. thank you for your answer!

Comment: What is the alternative without pygeos? When you have a lot of pickle objects before pygeos, you are getting the bug `KeyError: 0`, more [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1586).

Comment: @hhh The code above will work even without pygeos with geopandas 0.8

Comment: @martinfleis did pygeos get integrated to geopandas 0.8?

Comment: @hhh only optionally - https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/install.html#using-the-optional-pygeos-dependency

Comment: I am trying to understand whether this answer could solve the problem [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/378195/elevations-on-streets-with-python-geopandas-intersection-of-linestrings-and-poi) where with elevation data as Geopandas Points and streets as Geopandas LineStrings, in separate geopandas dataframes with separate geometry objects. I want to form a geopandas data frame of streets and left join it with elevation points. Then I would like to plot the streets with elevation colours, ideas? I tried the intersection first as here but not sure whether the right approach.

Comment: What does sindex do? Does the code work also without it? Is it just a speedup thing?