# Not able to find out if polygons in one shapefile intersect with polygons in other shapefile using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas

Santa Barbara contains some places from `CA_Places`. But when I use `intersects`, I get noting but all False. I have spent hours on this. Both shapefiles are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Esr0gFElpD1mWH3sIcPl0oJjVsUnXBCP?usp=sharing) for reference.

```
CA_Counties = geopandas.read_file("CA_Counties\\CA_Counties_TIGER2016.shp")
CA_places = geopandas.read_file("CA_Places\\CA_Places_TIGER2016.shp")
Santa_Barbara = CA_Counties[CA_Counties['NAME'] == 'Santa Barbara']
CA_places.intersects(Santa_Barbara)
```

All I'm getting is this warning:

```
C:\Users\LENOVO\.conda\envs\gdal_home\lib\site-packages\geopandas\base.py:39: UserWarning: The indices of the two GeoSeries are different.
warn("The indices of the two GeoSeries are different.")
```

Comment: Look at this question- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375407/geopandas-intersects-doesnt-find-any-intersection

Comment: @Llaves This answer worked well but I don't know why this geopanda's developers keep things complicated. The process I shown should have worked without any hassle.

Comment: I agree this seems like an odd design  choice